# Same server_name but different port number along with different user on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need to achieve something like, when user hit Domain IP/Keepalived Ip like z.z.z.z , basic http authentication should ask username and password. Now if user name is vikas it should redirect to z.z.z.z:5601 and if the user is gopal it should redirect to z.z.z.z:5602.

So here I have one major dependency on user , like I need to check before redirection if the user is Vikas or Gopal . I am trying following but it only works fine if I use single Location stenza .

```
upstream kibana {
        server 171.x.x.x:5601;
        server 172.x.x.x:5601;
        }
upstream kibana2 {
        server 171.x.x.x:5602;
        server 172.x.x.x:5602;
        }
        server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name z.z.z.z;
        location / {
        auth_basic      "protect kibana";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://kibana;
                }
        location / {
        auth_basic      "protect kibana";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswdkibana2.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://kibana2;
                }
        }
```

So in the second location directive I am using different http password file . So now the situation is , web page is asking user name and password but it does not pick any of them , I entered the credentials , it clears it and again asking for credentials . Can someone please help me to achieve this .

Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that by inspecting the name of the user and send them to a backend based on that

```
map $remote_user $server_based_on_user {
   "vikas" "kibana";
   "gopal" "kibana2";
}

upstream kibana {

    server 171.x.x.x:5601;
    server 172.x.x.x:5601;
}

upstream kibana2 {

    server 171.x.x.x:5602;
    server 172.x.x.x:5602;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name z.z.z.z;

    location / {
        auth_basic "protect kibana";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://$server_based_on_user$request_uri;
    }
}
```

The `/etc/nginx/htpasswd.user` file should have both the users defined

Comment: Thanks for the reply , with above i am able to login with vikas user and site is opening , but when I am trying with gopal user I am getting "502 Bad Gateway" nginx error . Can you please suggest what this could be ?

Comment: This is what I can see in the /var/log/nginx error.log "172.x.x.x - - [15/Sep/2017:02:35:20 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 597 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
171.x.x.x - gv [15/Sep/2017:02:35:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36""

Comment: I wish I could have shown you my screen , trust me this is exactly I see in the error.log file . So to cross check I checked my nginx.conf file to see where I am storing the error log so it is under /var/log/nginx/error.log; and the output is from the error.log file only . Is there anything else which I can provide you , this error file is full with only these lines when I do tail -f error.log.

Comment: Try reversing the names in the map config and see what happens. Also is it possible that `171.x.x.x:5602` is down?

Comment: You are the Man , your last comment saved my life :) so the problem was with the IP , my bad I have mistakenly mentioned the wrong IP . Seriously that was a silly mistake at my end .Now, I can open web page with both the users . Thanks a ton Tarun .May I ask one more question here , can I achieve the same with LDAP integration ? So I have 3 clients and they want LDAP integration to access the web page  so my plan is to restrict client 1 LDAP users ot their respective webpage and so on .

Comment: You can try and if it doesn't work post a new question